# Open-source: licence header on each source file OR a single COPYING OR both?

Tags: licensing

Publishing an open-source project, is it enough to add a **COPYING** file to the package or do I need to copy and paste it on top of every project's source file?
On famous public repositories like [github](http://github.com) or Google code I've seen different mixed approaches so I would like to know how this aspect should be handled correctly.

Comment: Not from a legal view, but from a developer's view: Having the license in every file is EXTREMELY ANNOYING. Especially if you want to search for e.g. a function/variable which is named like a word used in the license block..

Comment: Usually people put it in a file named COPYING without any extensions.

Comment: +1 I'm so glad I've found this question. I was about to lose my mind researching about this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming.

Comment: This question is about liscencing a script which is something each programmer should know....
As its very pertinent question however with a lot of upvotes I don't see a point to deprive people of such a ressource.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Working for a company that takes copyrights *very* seriously, we are required to put copyright/licence messages in every single file, despite the fact it's not technically required under US law.

I suspect it's so that, if a file was somehow separated from the product as a whole, it would still be easily identifiable.

However, we don't maintain that message in every single file. We have scripts which automatically add in the copyright messages to every file that's released to the wild. That way you only have to change one file.

We also have scripts that check every single release file has the correct message.

However, in terms of licensing, the lack of an explicit licence means that standard copyright would apply so it may be that you're happy with the single `LICENCE.txt` file.

As always, my legal opinion is worth every cent you paid me for it (which is zero). I am not a lawyer, I am certainly not *your* lawyer.

Comment: "my legal opinion is worth every cent you paid me for it (which is zero)" caustic but i loved it :)

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean to be caustic, it's just drummed into us by the work lawyers that legal advice offered by non-legal bods is a _very_ serious offence.

Comment: You'd better hope that stackoverflow votes don't qualify as legal tender.

Comment: my +1 was simply for the last line :) Well, I liked your answer overall but that last line was just killer :)

Comment: "[...] legal advice offered by non-legal bods is a very serious offence [sic]". Haha. A likely story.

Answer (score 6):

Each license creator has its own set of guidelines. Is it GPL? Then you may want to follow the GNU official guide, which you can find here (they require each file to be prefixed):

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html

Check out some resources too:

http://www.oss-watch.ac.uk/resources/opensourceyourcode.xml#body.1_div.3
http://producingoss.com/en/license-quickstart.html

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what license I'm using. For example, licenses like the GPL apply to the work as a whole, so I just put a `COPYING` file at the source root, and then make a note on each source file, as per the FSF's recommendations. On the other hand, if I release code under a BSD or MIT license (or something similar), I usually don't bother with a separate license file, and just put the license info in the source file itself (it seems likely that, with a BSD or MIT license, people would grab individual source files and use the code).

If you're asking on behalf of a "big, important" project, you'll want to consult with a lawyer.

Comment: I've released it with BSD and i have just a LICENCE.txt file at the project root.

Comment: Does it matter whether it's called COPYING or LICENSE? Are other names acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on KDE marble and in KDE we put license text in each file.

Comment: That's not true, I really doubt every file in Marble has the complete giant text of the GPL ;) What you have is a short header saying it's licensed under the GPL, and pointing at the full text elsewhere.